# How do I add or remove columns from a Data Grid View dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView form in my .NET application and I'd like to be able to show or hide additional columns based on a Boolean value at run time.

What's the best way to show/hide these columns in code (as opposed to in the Forms Designer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option (if the columns are known ahead of time) is to add them as you would normally, then set [`Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.visible.aspx) as appropriate (on each) at runtime.

You can also add extra columns completely at runtime (if you can't predict the schema) - but note that this might work differently depending on whether you are using data-binding (i.e. a [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

DataGridView contains a property Columns, which is a DataGridViewColumnCollection.

I believe in this collection, you can set which columns exist, and if they are visible.

For more info, start here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx